# How to use OneSignal notification buttons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I am using OneSignal API for sending and receiving notifications with my Flutter app. And I don't know how to use the buttons that can be added to the notification to open my flutter app to a specific screen.

My use case of the API is to create a notification template that has a button on it and send it to my users. But I don't know how to set a listener on that button that will open my flutter app.

I am using onesignal-node package for my node server.

```
let firstNotification = new OneSignal.Notification({
            template_id: "727f42a8-0b45-470e-ac9e-908f64af44ba",
            include_external_user_ids: [_id]
        });

        myClient.sendNotification(firstNotification, function (err, httpResponse, data) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            } else {
                console.log(data, httpResponse.statusCode);
                return res.status(200).send("Notification sent to " + user);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution

```
buttons: [
    OSActionButton(text: "text button 1", id: "id1"),
    OSActionButton(text: "text button 2", id: "id2")
],
```

but i dont know how i set an event to the button =(